# Get all woocommerce payment status is processing

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I m looking for a way to count all woocommerce orders that the status is "processing".
I looked for woocommerce_payment_complete/status hooks but cant figure out how to make a counter.

I need to add to my Woocomerce emails a new number/orderNumber that is not the normal woo order number but the new number that is the count of the complete payment
(example:
order:1, payment number :1
order:2, no payment
order:3, payment number:2
...
)

can anyone point me in a direction where I can start?

Comment: You can save the data as an order meta when the order changes to `wc-processing` status. To do this you could use the `woocommerce_order_status_processing` hook. While you can add a prefix or a suffix to the order number via this hook: `woocommerce_order_number`.

Comment: @Vdgaetano Thanks for the approach. I found some reading about this hooks, but I m used to work with JavaScript so Wordpress php it s still new to me.